# Вложенные множества: поддержка целостности

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поддерживать целостность данных в MSSql для вложенных множеств (Nested Set).

Если я правильно понимаю, используются либо триггеры, либо целостность поддерживается при вставке / обновлении (в процедурах). Может еще какие-то варианты используются... Какой способ является наиболее оптимальным и если вас не затруднит, хотелось бы увидеть пример реализации.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Без выполнения кода в том или ином виде (процедуры\триггеры и т.д.) не обойтись, т.к. вам при вставке в середину всегда придётся обновлять правую часть дерева. А для MSSQL более оптимальным выглядит "список смежных вершин" (Adjacency List), т.к. в MSSQL есть обобщённые табличные выражения, нормальная работа с иерархией и поддерживать целостность просто через ключи с каскадным обновлением/удалением.